# Can't Parse Array JSON Decoder Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

I can't get the JSON data of the link it always get the error. `"Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."` Thank you.

My JSON

```
{
server_response: [
{
id: "1",
magazine_title: "Volume 1 Issue 1",
mobile_link: "",
magazine_img: "https://www.pcbuyersguide.com.ph/wp-content/uploads/magazine_cover/pcbg.png",
mobile_zip: ""
},
{
id: "2",
magazine_title: "Volume 1 Issue 2",
mobile_link: "",
magazine_img: "https://www.pcbuyersguide.com.ph/wp-content/uploads/magazine_cover/pcbg.png",
mobile_zip: ""
},
{
id: "3",
magazine_title: "Volume 1 Issue 4",
mobile_link: "",
magazine_img: "https://www.pcbuyersguide.com.ph/wp-content/uploads/magazine_cover/pcbg.png",
mobile_zip: ""
},
{
id: "4",
magazine_title: "Volume 2 Issue 1",
mobile_link: "",
magazine_img: "https://www.pcbuyersguide.com.ph/wp-content/uploads/magazine_cover/pcbg.png",
mobile_zip: ""
}]
```

My Struct

```
struct Root: Decodable{

       var server_response: [server_details]
    }

    struct server_details: Decodable{

        var  magazine_title : String
        var magazine_img : String
        var mobile_link: String

    }
```

My Fetch from data server function

```
  // FETCH MAGAZINE
func fetchDatafromServer(){

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.pcbuyersguide.com.ph/wp-content/mobileapp/pcbg_magazine_data.php") else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, res, err) in

        guard let data = data else {return}

        do{
            let articles = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from: data)

            for info in articles {

                self.magazine_title.append(info.server_response[1].magazine_title)


            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch let jsonErr{

            print(jsonErr)
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying `decode([Root].self...`, as if your JSON were an array of Root. But it is not an array of Root. It is a Root. Say `decode(Root.self`.

Then change

```
for info in articles
```

To

```
for info in articles.server_response
```

That is the array.

Comment: if I remove the array on ` Root.self  ` I get this error in for  `Type 'Root' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence`

Comment: Your comment is about a totally different mistake where you say `for info in articles`. That is wrong too. But it has nothing to do with what you asked!  For what you asked my answer is right.